# getting 401 response codes on a deployed React App that worked fine in development?

Tags: node.js, github, react-redux, production-environment, http-status-code-401

I am trying to complete a Redux project and got everything to work fine in development on my own machine but when deployed, the browser is failing to recognise my hidden environment variables so not passing client keys to Api calls and thus making unauthorised requests. I have a '.env' file with the keys in them and then refer thus...

const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY}&units=metric`;

I have looked up the problem on here and think I understand what's going wrong but don't know how to put it right. I am deploying site via Netlify from my Github repo and my build settings appear to be correct. I thought 'npm run build' took care of all that for me?

99% finished a project and now scratching my head furiously...

Comment: How do you define and use the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining variables in .env file starting with `REACT_APP` like:

```
REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID=4
REACT_APP_API_URL=/api
```

Try using it anywhere like:

```
const apiUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I have got my variables declared like that in '.env' file and that's sitting in root directory of project. It worked in development so I know the keys are good. I'm kind of newish to Github and followed all the steps to push project to repository, obviously the '.env' file is hidden from view there. All the hidden files are pushed as well aren't they?

Comment: I just tried along lines of what you suggested... console.logging those variables and returning undefined in browser but saying what they should in development. why isn't my '.env' file being recognised / processed?

Comment: if the .env file is hidden check the .gitignore file and remove the line .env and push again.

Comment: I fixed it.... hoooray! I had to go and specifically set the environment variables 'REACT_APP.....' in Environment Variable Settings from Deploy Settings. Phew.... Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variables specifically within the Netlify UI. So 'Deploy Settings > Environment > Environment Variables' then variable -'REACT_APP....' value - '*****' for each variable you want defined.